# New pop-up style for enter an amount in Android

Tags: android, popup, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

How can I customize the **pop-up** to enter an amount like below image.

[image]

Comment: Use `Gridview` in pop up window!

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. This library should help you:

https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

[image: Picker]

Comment: :I am getting so much error while importing this projects.can you please help me that how it overcomes.